# Is there any practical use for octonions?

Tags: quaternions, applications, hamilton-equations, octonions, hypercomplex-numbers

Quaternions are useful for describing orientation/ rotations in 3- dimensions, however is there much practical use for an 8-dimensional base hyper complex number *id est* **Octonions**?

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Applications) a starting point to look into

Comment: It might stretch the definition of "practical" (at least for the moment), but see: https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-octonion-math-that-could-underpin-physics-20180720/